# How can I parse only at collection-level instead of both model and collection level in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

As a newbie of backbone, I encountered a problem when fetching data from the server.

The server response is always in the structure of
{
 errcode:xxx,
 data:{object array}
}

And I defined parse in both model and collection:

```
parse:funciton(response){
   if(100==response.errcode){
      return response.data;
}
```

so when I save/fetch from model, it works properly.

However, when I fetch from collection, things won't work out as I expected. 
The response will firstly be parsed in collection and then parsed again in model.
I hope that the collection can pass the object to new a model without being parsed again at model-level.

I tried fetch{parse:false}. However, that will disable parse at both collection and model level.

Can I just disable parse at model-level when calling fetch at collection-level? Thanks!

Comment: why are you parsing both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply pass another option to your collection fetch method like so:

`collection.fetch({parseModel: false});`

and then check in your model's `parse` method if this option exists:

```
parse: function(resp, options) {
   if(!options.parseModel) return resp;
   // Do your parsing here
}
```

Even better, you could include the option by default in your collection's `fetch` method:

```
fetch: function(options) {
   options = _.extend({parseModel: false}, options);
   return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
```

Of course you'd have to set a default to for your model's `fetch` method too:

```
fetch: function(options) {
   options = _.extend({parseModel: true}, options);
   return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, I didn't get why I need to set default t my model's fetch method? I think if I extend only collection's fetch method, it won't have a effect when I fetch my model directly...Thanks!

Comment: The reason for it is that if you fetch the model alone with passing any options (`model.fetch()`), it won't go through the `parse` method because the `parseModel` option is not set anywhere. If you always want to parse the model when you do `model.fetch()`, then you need to set it as a default somewhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for parsing collection:

```
parse: function (response) {
    return response.data.map(function (data) {
        return {
            errcode: response.errcode,
            data: data
        };
    });
}
```